# Submission of manuscript in another journal

Tags: mathematics, paper-submission

I have submitted a manuscript in the "filomat" journal back in 2020-02-21. The paper's status is "under review" and it's been like that from the day of submission. I contacted the editor many times about the (real) status of the paper, but he didn't reply! I  wanted  to know why it takes so long for my  paper to be reviewed but he didn't reply!
I do want to withdraw the manuscript and submit it elsewhere, but I cannot withdraw it!
So, the situation is: I want to withdraw the paper but I can't! And I contacted the editor about this many times and he ignored! And the paper is there and I don't know what to do!
Any advice!
Thank you all

Comment: Why do you think you can't withdraw your paper? It doesn't require permission from the editor. The paper is yours, not theirs.

Comment: I don't think I can't withdraw the paper, I just don't know how to do it! I tried in vain!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate question, but I can't find one that answers directly.

All you need to do to withdraw a paper, prior to assigning copyright to them, is to inform them of the withdrawal. They have no rights to the paper unless you grant them. The fact that they don't respond is not essential. Just make it clear and unambiguous that you have withdrawn the paper.

Unfortunately there is no way to guarantee that they will see an email or admit that they have. A better solution, though now uncommon, is to send something like "registered mail" where you get a receipt when the post office delivers it. This probably isn't available everywhere, but it makes it clear.

Some email systems will have a similar function, sending you a notice when the mail is first opened. Keep copies of your correspondence, even if it is one sided.

It is unprofessional not to have answered your mail. A journal that is unprofessional in one way may also be unprofessional in others.

Comment: Would you please explain this "A better solution, though now uncommon, is to send something like "registered mail" where you get a receipt when the post office delivers it." in more details?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_mail